# extracting string from a line in Unix

Tags: regex, linux, sed, ksh

I've a file having content:

`code_name:00:12 vertical 01 1.3489:27 vsftypyre.01 [91.02.01.6] 29.05.2018 {1705}`

Expected Output:

`code_name:00:12 29.05.2018 {1705}`

I'm trying below command ,but it's not giving the result:

`sed '/\bvertical.*\]/d' file_name`

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use substitute command - `d` is for deleting entire line when given regex matches

```
$ sed 's/\bvertical.*\]//' ip.txt 
code_name:00:12  29.05.2018 {1705}

$ # ] doesn't require escaping
$ sed 's/\bvertical.*]//' ip.txt 
code_name:00:12  29.05.2018 {1705}
```

Note that `*` is greedy, so `.*]` will try to match as much as possible

```
$ echo 'good foo [123] baz [456]' | sed 's/foo.*]//'
good 

$ # this will delete only up to first ] after 'foo'
$ echo 'good foo [123] baz [456]' | sed 's/foo[^]]*]//'
good  baz [456]
```

Comment: Ah, i didn't realised `-d` would delete the entire line, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question wasn't tagged with `awk`, it's easy to use this tool extract some columns:

```
awk '{print $1,$(NF-1),$NF}' <<< "code_name:00:12 vertical 01 1.3489:27 vsftypyre.01 [91.02.01.6] 29.05.2018 {1705}"
```

`NF` represents the number of fields of the current line, so `$NF` is the last element of that line.

Answer (score 0):

If the records in your file are always in that shape, 8 fields separated by white space, then awk may be a simpler solution:

```
> cat file_name 
  code_name:00:12 vertical 01 1.3489:27 vsftypyre.01 [91.02.01.6] 29.05.2018 {1705}
> cat file_name | awk '{ print $1, $7, $8 }'
  code_name:00:12 29.05.2018 {1705}
```

The above `awk` script meaning, for each record, print the 1st, 7th and 8th fields.